# How to parse tag content out of an XML string?

Tags: html, sql, sql-server, string, t-sql

I need to select specific HTML tags from string using SQL query as the following example :

```
<input type="hidden" value="x1.html" id="x1" />
<img src="x2" style="display:none" height="1" width="1" alt="" />
<input type="hidden" value="x3.html" id="x3" />
```

how to return only `<img/>` tag content as shown below:

```
<img src="x2" style="display:none" height="1" width="1" alt="" />
```

your response is highly appreciated

Comment: ...aaaaand what have you tried....?

Comment: ...aaaaaand for which RDBMS? Sql-Server? MySql? TeraData?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: In SQL Server db

Comment: @MohammadAbuSaloum do you need additional help with this? I have submitted an answer to your question.

Comment: @Brien I have new comments below , can you please check?

Comment: @Brien
exactly, how i can insert only <Img< tag into temp table when the string contains more than one

Comment: @Brien No it's the same one because i'm working with data stored as string not xml

Comment: Hello again! If you've found an answer here useful, please don't forget to accept one and vote it up. In doing so, you both get positive reputation and it helps future visitors to your question determine which answer is the most appropriate/helpful. If you've got any question about this, check out this link: [how-does-accepting-an-answer-work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 1):

Use [PATINDEX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/patindex-transact-sql) and [SUBSTRING](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql)

Find pattern index for start = 50

```
SELECT PATINDEX('%<img%',col1) FROM test
```

Find pattern index for length of substring = 65

```
SELECT PATINDEX('%>%',SUBSTRING(col1,PATINDEX('%<img%',col1),LEN(col1))) FROM test
```

Use in SUBSTRING

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(col1,PATINDEX('%<img%',col1),PATINDEX('%>%',SUBSTRING(col1,PATINDEX('%<img%',col1),LEN(col1)))) FROM test
```

[image]

[[DEMO HERE]](http://rextester.com/PHSSJY94104)

Comment: Thank you very much, but how i can insert it into table if I have multi one = the condition ?